# Why does node thinks my mongodb model is a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mern

I have a basic setup for a mern project with a UserModel in it.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)

module.exports = UserModel
```

In my package.json I've added `"type": "module",`

I import the UserModel via `import UserModel from './models/UserModel'`

When I run nodemon I get this error:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:40
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/bian/Documents/WebDev/fullstack/demoapp/models/UserModel' imported from /home/bian/Documents/WebDev/fullstack/demoapp/App.js
Did you mean to import ../models/UserModel.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:233:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  url: 'file:///home/bian/Documents/WebDev/fullstack/demoapp/models/UserModel',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I've googled and tried to set the type to `commonjs` and imported via require but nothing works

Can anyone explain what is going on and/or how to fix it?

Comment: When you're using ES module `import`, you have to export symbols with `export`, not the CommonJS `module.exports`.

Comment: And when you `import` from a path in your project you have to specify the full file name, including `.js` or `.mjs`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `import mongoose from "mongoose"` with `const mongoose = require("mongoose")`

Comment: That's not the `import` that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace :

```
import UserModel from './models/UserModel'
```

```
import UserModel from '../models/UserModel'
```